# Permission denied when trying to change browser window title

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I have a servlet that generates a PDF and the output goes to a new browser window.
I am attempting to replace the title of that new window using the updateTitle() function below.
However, when I try to assign the report name (repName) to the window instance, IE11 throws a "Permission denied" error.  Any ideas?

```
function showReport(url, repName){

    var repWin = window.open(url);
    updateTitle(repWin, repName)
}

function updateTitle(repWin, repName) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        repWin.document.title = repName; //IE11 console throws PERMISSION DENIED here
    }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: Are they the same domain?

Comment: It might have to do with "cross site" that IE thinks that to different windows are two different sites and that one is not allowed to change the other.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use something like [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage).

On your original window:

```
function showReport(url, repName) {
   var repWin = window.open(url);
   repWin.postMessage('setTitle:' + repName, '*');
}
```

On the `repWin`:

```
function updateTitle(message) {
    var m = message.data.split(':'),
        eventType = m[0],
        data = m[1];
    if (message.origin ===  'YOUR_URL_HERE' && eventType === 'setTitle' ) {
         repWin.document.title = data; 
    }
}

window.addEventListener("message", updateTitle, false);
```

**Note:** This will obviously only work if you can modify the source for the window you are opening.

Comment: Esteban, repWin.postMessage('setTitle:' + repName, ''); throws an "Invalid procedure call or argument."

Comment: I see you just added a note too.  Yeah, unfortunately there's no source to edit as the url being passed is a servlet call that returns the PDF OutputStream.  No JSPs involved.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Is there any way you can host that servlet through the same domain as the originating app?

Comment: Everything is actually in the same application, so I'm not sure why IE is thinking that they are not from the same domain.

Comment: Are you sure they're the same domain? Subdomains matter as well so `domaineone.app.com` will not be able to access `domaintwo.app.com`. Are you able to share the URLs you are using?

Comment: Does port matter? The URL in my original browser goes like http://10.10.1.200:9081/MyApp/Main.jsp  and when I try to display repWin.document.domain, the value is "10.10.1.200" only.

Comment: @MarkLogan Yes! Port definitely matters. See [how to change document domain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Changing_origin). Unfortunately you will probably run into the same issue as adding the `postMessage` event listener.